# Convergence of stopped/unstopped Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, weak-convergence, stopping-times

Does weak convergence of stopped Markov chains implies weak convergence of the corresponding unstopped Markov chains in some particular case?

In my case:

**Assumptions on the sequence of Markov chains:**

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

- $\{X^n(t)\}_{t\geq 0 }\subset \frac{1}{n}\mathbb{N}^d\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}$ Markov chain
- $\tau_n=\inf\{t:X_i^n(t)= \frac{1}{n} \text{ for some } i\}$ is a finite stopping time
- if $s\geq t$ then $||X^n(s)||_1\leq ||X^n(t)||_1$
- $X^n(0)\to \mathbf{x}_0\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^d$

**Assumptions on the limiting process:**

- $\{X(t)\}_{t\geq 0 }  \subset \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^d$ strongly continuous Markov process
- $X(0)=\mathbf{x}_0$
- $\forall t\geq ||\mathbf{x}_0||_1,  X(t)=\mathbf{0}$.
- $\inf\{t:X_i(t)= 0 \text{ for some } i\}=||\mathbf{x}_0||_1$

**Weak convergence:**

- We know that
  $\{X^n(t\wedge \tau_n)\}_{t\geq 0}$ converges weakly to $X$.

I am trying to prove that  $X^n$ should also converge weakly to $X$, because, heuristically, it seems that this is implied by $\tau_n\to ||\mathbf{x}_0||_1$, $X^n(\tau_n)\to X(||\mathbf{x}_0||_1)=\mathbf{0}$ and for $t\geq \tau_n$,  $||X^n(t) ||_1\leq ||X^n(\tau_n)||_1\to 0$.

Is my intuition correct? Is there any classical result that could help me here?

Comment: is there anything wrong with the proof you wrote? You know that $|X^n(\tau_n)|_1 = 1/n$, so you are not even using continuity here when you take the limit. I could be missing something of course.

Comment: One of the components of $X^n(\tau_n)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{n}$, $||X^n(\tau_n)||_1$ could be larger than $\frac{1}{n}$. The "proof" I wrote does not seem rigorous enough to me.